# Difference between a container and a database?

Tags: c#, database, collections

I am trying to understand the difference between a container such as a Dictionary or List and a SQL Database.

I am sorry if this is a stupid question but I am trying to understand when each one is necessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [faq] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Dictionary and List are Objects in a Language and are non persistent, wheras a Database is a persistent data-storage

Comment: The "containers" you mention are [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure), and databases are [an entirely different beast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).

Answer (score 3):

A collection (the most common name for an object/value container) usually stores objects/values in memory while a database persists information to a disk drive, storing it until it's removed.

Comment: The collections are just interfaces. There's nothing to say where or how the data is actually stored. Yes, I'm being nitpicky.

Comment: More splitting hairs: technically a database doesn't need to be persistent. Wikipedia says: "A database is an organized collection of data". (.NET) collections are databases, too, if you want.

Comment: Every organized collection of anything is a database. Not every database is a SQL database.

Comment: That's a bit pedantic: this answer is acceptable considering the level of the question. However, *could* be improved with caveats of "usually stored in memory" and "specific to a language", and "databases are often/more commonly persisted to disk" etc etc...

Comment: @Catcall it's reasonably to use the term "database" as a synonym for "SQL database" or "relational database." Overall, this question is simply too broad, and should be closed, not answered.